# How to command line extract svg from pdf using inkscape?

Tags: pdf, svg, command, inkscape

Is there a command line option for asking inkscape to extract svg from pdf page 3 (for example)?
The command I use now is

```
$ inkscape -f test.pdf -l test.svg
```

but I would like also the option to export a specific page from this pdf.

Answer (score 2):

What about extracting the page you need with `pdftk` (or in fact, any other suitable tool) first:

```
mypage=$(mktemp -u XXXXXX.pdf)
pdftk test.pdf cat 3 output "$mypage"
inkscape -l test.svg "$mypage"
rm "$mypage"
```

(It would be nice to be able to pipe the output from `pdftk` directly to `inkscape`. Unfortunately, when provided from stdin, data are expected by `inkscape` to be svg. A named pipe doesn't help either, because `inkscape` seems to attempt to traverse pdf files more than once.)